# How do you convert something like 400..900 to filter values from an array of 400,500,600,700,800,900,1000

Tags: javascript, filter, filtering

I got this from google fonts api so if you put a request for a font you want many weights you could basically ask for 400..900. That would basically give you every font weight from 400 to 900 or one had to write 400,500,600,700,800,900.

I want to use that same logic, it can be done using splitting that and running through a filtering loop. I want to know if there is a better way to do this. That can be more useful and native. I don't want to split them. I am curious of a better solution.

```js
let a = '400..900';
a = a.split('..');
let b = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000].filter((x) => (x >= a[0] && x <= a[1]))
console.log(a,b);
// 400,500,600,700,800,900
```

Comment: shouldn't you use `&&` instead of `||` ? in your code b will have all element from the array, as that expression is always true

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: not really, and I don;t think you should be asking for opinions on this site

Comment: I am looking for a solution, not the opinion, since APIs get complex very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is honestly pretty solid and the way I would go about it. There isn't going to be a fundamentally better way then using a filter.

If you wanted to make it a little more readable, you could destructure your split `a` into separate variables. You also have a few extra parentheses.

Also, moving the list of values to a constant you reuse instead of re-declaring every time can help.

```js
const values = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];
let a = '400..900';
const [start, end] = a.split('..');
let b = values.filter(x => x >= start && x <= end)
console.log(start, end, b);
```

However, all of these are really, really super minor and/or simply stylistic changes.

As for not wanting to use `split`, there isn't really a way around it and there isn't really a reason to avoid it. `split` is fairly quick. An alternative would be to use Regex (`^(\d+)\.\.(\d+)$`) but I'd definitely consider that worse both from a performance and readability standpoint.

Otherwise, if you knew they were only going to give you 3-digit values, you could use substring, but again, that's worse for readability and it would mess up if they gave 1000.

Comment: I also don't want to use Regex they are not performant. I was curious why would google choose this way of doing this, I guess their api is already pretty complex they don't mind a few extra ifs.

Comment: Honestly, trying to get rid of `split` falls firmly into the realm of "micro-optimization" and really isn't worth the effort unless you need to run trillions of these in a very short time frame.

Comment: Definitely that would be micro optimization is there a nomenclature for writing like 400..900? just curious.

Comment: Nope. If you want to avoid split you'd simply have to take them in as two separate values.

Answer (score 3):

You could use for loop with step of 100

```js
const a = "400..900"
const [start, end] = a.split("..").map(Number)

const res = []
for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 100) {
  res.push(i)
}

console.log(res)
```

For arbitrary separator between these 2 number, you could use regex to extract the begin and the end

```js
const a = "400---------|||||||||---------900"
const [_, start, end] = /(\d+)\D+(\d+)/.exec(a).map(Number)

const res = []
for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 100) {
  res.push(i)
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I want to do it without splitting them.

Comment: @Navanshu Rastogi what hgb123 suggests is the cleanest approach. There is nothing bad with splitting

Comment: This would work if your guaranteed that they all exist. But if there is a scenario where it isn't all of them for some reason, you'd be in trouble with this approach.

Comment: Yes, that is also there, with every request you have to check if there is '..' in the request and that becomes a long chain of if and else. What would one do if there is no .. characters.

Comment: @NavanshuRastogi I've just updated the answer for the case of arbitrary separator

Comment: I want to keep it simplified this is quite complex. So there is no inbuilt function that uses this way of nomenclature 400..900. I guess with nomenclature things are simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a more dynamic way like so

```js
const input = '400..900';
const bounds = input.split('..').map(x => parseInt(x));

const getAllInbetween = (bounds, stepSize) => {
  const steps = (bounds[1] - bounds[0]) / stepSize + 1; // Calculate how many steps are needed between the bounds

  return new Array(steps) // Create an array with the size of the amount of steps
    .fill(0) // Fill it with zeroes 
    .map((_, i) => i * stepSize + bounds[0]) // loop over it and assign the values, using the current array index
}

console.log(getAllInbetween(bounds, 100));
```

Comment: This would work if your guaranteed that they all exist. But if there is a scenario where it isn't all of them for some reason, you'd be in trouble with this approach.

Comment: True statement, although it was never mentioned, that some could not exist @samanime

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stricter way, with regexps.

It's not necessarily better perf but I believe it's more robust / tailored for your purpose.

```js
const query = '400..600';
const sizes = [400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];
const match = /^(([4-9]|10)00)\.\.(([4-9]|10)00)$/.exec(query);

if (!match) {
  throw "Invalid input string"
}

const offset = sizes[0]/100;
console.log(sizes.slice(+match[2] - offset, +match[4] + 1 - offset));
```

Answer (score 0):

My version

```js
const a = '400..900';
const [from,to] = a.split('..');
const b = Array(Math.ceil((to - from + 100)/100)).fill().map((_, i) => (+from + (i*100)))
console.log(b)
```